# Создание и использование dll c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

Нужно написать глобальный хук на клавиатуру и мышь с общей памятью. Использую Visual Studio 2015. После чтения и использования большого количества мануалов - не один не заработал. В данный момент создал dll проект. В нём добавил два файла main.cpp main.def

dll main.cpp

```
__declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Heey"), TEXT("qwe"), MB_OK);
    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

dll main.def

```
LIBRARY "hookDll"
EXPORTS
keyboardHook
```

exe main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    HHOOK hHook;
    HINSTANCE hInstDll;
    HOOKPROC hookProc;

    hInstDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("moreDll.dll"));
    hookProc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hInstDll, "keyboardHook");  

    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, hookProc, hInstDll, 0);
    getchar();
    getchar();

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    FreeLibrary(hInstDll);

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Dll загружается, дело в том, что dll проект был назван MoreDll, и при сборке я получаю MoreDll.dll. Но я в `GetProcAddress()` я получаю ошибку 127 - данная процедура не может быть найдена. Я читал про манглинг, но по-моему в моём случае его не должно быть.

Ниже код из dll, который хотелось бы использовать, но не понимаю  как с ним взаимодействовать из .exe, и как грамотно скомпилировать его в dll.

```
//
// some data will be shared across all
// instances of the DLL
//
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.SHARED,RWS")
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
int iKeyCount = 0;
HHOOK hKeyboardHook = 0;
HHOOK hMouseHook = 0;
#pragma data_seg()

//
// instance specific data
//
HMODULE hInstance = 0;

//
// DLL load/unload entry point
//
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, 
                      DWORD  dwReason, 
                      LPVOID lpReserved)
{
   switch (dwReason)
   {
   case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH :
      hInstance = (HINSTANCE) hModule;
      break;

   case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH :
      break;

   case DLL_THREAD_DETACH :
      break;

   case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH :
      break;
   }
   return TRUE;
}

//
// keyboard hook
//
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code,       // hook code
                              WPARAM wParam,  // virtual-key code
                              LPARAM lParam)  // keystroke-message information
{
   if ((lParam & 0x80000000) != 0)
   {
      ++iKeyCount;
   }
   return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

//
// mouse hook
//
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int code,       // hook code
                           WPARAM wParam,  // message identifier
                           LPARAM lParam)  // mouse coordinates
{
   switch (wParam)
   {
   case WM_LBUTTONDOWN :
   case WM_MBUTTONDOWN :
   case WM_RBUTTONDOWN :
   case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK :
   case WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK :
   case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK :
      ++iKeyCount;
      break;
   }
   return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

//
// install keyboard/mouse hooks
//
void KBM_API InstallHooks(void)
{
   hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
   hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, MouseProc, hInstance, 0);
}

//
// remove keyboard/mouse hooks
//
void KBM_API RemoveHooks(void)
{
   UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
   UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
   hKeyboardHook = hMouseHook = 0;
}

//
// retrieve number of keystrokes
//
int KBM_API FetchKeyCount(bool bClear)
{
   int kc = iKeyCount;
   if (bClear)
      iKeyCount = 0;
   return kc;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите с помощью Dependency Walker, какое именно имя у функции, экспортируемой из DLL.

Comment: Мне кажется, в определении функций нужно использовать extern "C"

Comment: @Arhad Спасибо, помогло, DependencyWalker показал что имя `_keyboardHook@12`. Добавил extern "C" и функцию без extern "C".  `_keyboardHook@12` там, где язык С, а для другой язык С++ такое имя  `?procName@@YAHHH@Z`. А ещё показал, что не удаётся найти некоторые модули, но hook сработал)

Comment: `_keyboardHook@12` – это декорирование имён соглашения вызова *stdcall*, присущего Windows API. Соответствующее ключевое слово `__stdcall` объявлено в макросе `CALLBACK`.

Comment: И да, попробуйте убрать `__declspec(dllexport)`. Возможно, оно обладает более высоким приоритетом, чем недекорированное объявление в `.def`-файле.